# ¿Cómo quitar el espacio al seleccionar un item del autocomplete jquery UI?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui

Buenas tardes quisiera saber como puedo quitar el espacio que sale al seleccionar con la tecla **tab** un elemento del autocomplete cuando lo selecciono.Gracias de antemano.

**Observación**: El Json contiene espacios en el campo NUMERO_PROYECTO, quizás por ello carga el autocomplete con espacios como podría eliminar ese espacio.

archivo.json

```
{"data":[{"NUMERO_PROYECTO":"103438    ","NOMBRE_PROYECTO":"DIST__DS-CANVIA- SWF-AGILE CO","ALIAS":null,"GERENTE_PROYECTO":null,"INICIO_PLANIFICADO":null,"TERMINO_PLANIFICADO":null,"BU":null,"LINIA":null,"ESTADO":null,"TIPO":null},{"NUMERO_PROYECTO":"101495    ","NOMBRE_PROYECTO":"SLIN__DS-CANVIA-SWF-AGILE","ALIAS":null,"GERENTE_PROYECTO":null,"INICIO_PLANIFICADO":null,"TERMINO_PLANIFICADO":null,"BU":null,"LINIA":null,"ESTADO":null,"TIPO":null},{"NUMERO_PROYECTO":"100959    ","NOMBRE_PROYECTO":"PROY__DS-CANVIA-TESTING INT","ALIAS":null,"GERENTE_PROYECTO":null,"INICIO_PLANIFICADO":null,"TERMINO_PLANIFICADO":null,"BU":null,"LINIA":null,"ESTADO":null,"TIPO":null},{"NUMERO_PROYECTO":"103569    ","NOMBRE_PROYECTO":"DIST_DS-CANVIA-SOP FUNC SIST","ALIAS":null,"GERENTE_PROYECTO":null,"INICIO_PLANIFICADO":null,"TERMINO_PLANIFICADO":null,"BU":null,"LINIA":null,"ESTADO":null,"TIPO":null},{"NUMERO_PROYECTO":"103045    ","NOMBRE_PROYECTO":"DIST__DS-CANVIA-SERV SWF","ALIAS":null,"GERENTE_PROYECTO":null,"INICIO_PLANIFICADO":null,"TERMINO_PLANIFICADO":null,"BU":null,"LINIA":null,"ESTADO":null,"TIPO":null}]}
```

Autocomplete.js

```
$("#IdProyecto").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: root + '/Sigeri/ObtenerProyectos',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { Prefix: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.NUMERO_PROYECTO, value: item.NUMERO_PROYECTO };
                    }))

                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "No results found.",
            results: function (count) {
                return count + (count > 1 ? ' results' : ' result ') + ' found';
            }
        }
    });
```

Muestro la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: saludos puedes usar algo asi "label:$.trim(item.NUMERO_PROYECTO)".. de igual manera para el value..."value: $.trim(item.NUMERO_PROYECTO)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías aplicarle [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim) a `item.NUMERO_PROYECTO` y así evitar que la opción aparezca con espacios.

#### Ejemplo

```
response($.map(data, function (item) {
  let num = item.NUMERO_PROYECTO.trim();
  return {label: num, value: num};
}));
```

Comment: Excelente,Gracias.